# tfs emailing problem

Tags: visual-studio

I want to send an email automatically when I assigned a task to a person in team foundation server.

how can i do?

Comment: ı know how to use email alert from administrator console. but I think I should have to enter the password that mail but where???

Answer (score 0):

Either [setup an alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400808.aspx) for every single person in your team. It is not possible to use a field in the work item to define the recipient of the e-mail. It is not possible to use a smtp server that needs authorization.

Another option is to [create your own action to send the email](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/How-to-use-WCF-to-subscribe-to-the-TFS-2010-Event-Service-rolling-up-hours.aspx)